# terraform .11 to .12 change caused empty lists to matter

Tags: terraform

In 0.11 we had a module that create a google host.  The module will create
it in one of two ways depending on the arguments passed in, using one of
two different resource statements, i.e.

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "this_public" {
  count = var.instance_count * var.flag
}
resource "google_compute_instance" "this_private" {
  count = var.instance_count * (1 - var.flag)
}
```

(Grossly simplified, but equivalent)

For output we'd collect both possible resources, slam them together and take which ever one wasn't blank.  (given the code, one OR the other would generate, never both, so it's guaranteed that one of these strucutures is empty.)

```
  this_instance_id = compact(
    concat(
      coalescelist(
        google_compute_instance.this_public.*.id,
        google_compute_instance.this_private.*.id,
      ),
      [""],
    ),
  )
```

This fails miserably now because tf 0.12 cares that one of those two is empty,
and it can't collesce it.

I can't see how to make this work again without completely redesigning it
with lots and lots of for loops on the various elements.

Comment: I put some different approaches in my answer below, but I'm also a little baffled as to why `coalescelist` would reject an empty list in the first place, since selecting the first _non-empty_ list is the whole point of that function. Could you update your question to include the full error message Terraform generated with this configuration? Perhaps there's something more subtle going on here...

Comment: I solved my problem by using the new dynamic features so I don't need multiple versions, it puts the missing bits in as needed.  I'll see if I can roll back a file and try it in a new branch.  Basically it was complaining that the this_private branch didn't exist so was picky about getting *.id out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that these two resources are essentially mutually exclusive, I think an expression like the following would produce an equivalent result:

```
concat(
  google_compute_instance.this_public.*.id,
  google_compute_instance.this_private.*.id,
)
```

Since one of those two lists is guaranteed to be empty, this will always be a list of `var.instance_count` items concatenated with an empty list, which I think gets the result you were looking for here.

A different way to do it, which may be more explicit to future readers of this configuration, would be to rely on the conditional operator which is now fully general for all types of value in Terraform 0.12:

```
var.flag != 0 ?
  google_compute_instance.this_public.*.id :
  google_compute_instance.this_private.*.id
```